# get value from a row on button click

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

i need to get the value from a row to console i have a row with 20 items on clicking on specific item in that row list i should get the value to my console could some one help me

```
    <ion-row (click)="changeData($event)">
        <ion-col>{{item.day}}/{{item.month}}/{{item.year}}</ion-col>
        <ion-col>{{item.quantity}}</ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-icon name="ion-checkmark-round"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>{{item.brand}}</ion-col>
        <ion-col>{{item.price}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>

</ion-grid>

changeData(value){
        console.log("row clicked, values like brand,price..etc should be displayed here",value)
    }
```

Comment: What value do you want to get?

Comment: values inside each col   <ion-col>{{item.day}}/{{item.month}}/{{item.year}}</ion-col>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it in `click` event

```
<ion-row>
 <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClick(item)">{{item...}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>
itemClick(item){
   console.log(item);
}
```